# How can I caption my figure in a right way?

Tags: captions

I was writing an article and try to insert an image with a caption. So first I used the following codes,

```
\flashright
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{cantor.png}
```

which results in

[image]

Then I wanted to add a caption below the image, so I used the following codes

```
\begin{figure}
\flushright
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{cantor.png}
\caption{cantor set}
\end{figure}
```

which gave me,

[image]

So my question is how can I fix this large gap and make the things look like the first image with the caption underneath the image?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `\flushright` outside the `figure` ?

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so we have a complete minimal example rather than a mere fragment. It is not really possible to help you without this. However, @Nasser 's suggestion will certainly not do what you want ;).

Comment: That said, you do not really have that gap. When you write some more text, the gap will fill up with the content. The `figure` is a float and it is floating to the bottom of the page. If you don't want a float, don't use a float environment i.e. don't use `figure`. Use `\captionof` from the `caption` or `capt-of` packages if you need a caption.

Comment: @cfr I was guessing. no MWE so can't try and I am not going to go make a MWE just to try ;)

Answer (score 3):

i assume you only used figure for the caption, not to float the image.  The `\captionof` macro can be used pretty much anywhere.

The `\caption` or `\captionof` macro starts and ends with `\par`, so it has to go into a `\parbox` or `minipage`.  Also, the caption isn't just centered; it is centered in a space `\textwidth` wide (like `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}`), so you need to use a `minipage` to reduce `\textwidth` (`\parbox` won't work)

In this case I made the `minipage` the same width as the image.

OTOH, if this is for an article you probably want something like wrapfig.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or caption
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool, outlines text area

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}}
\flushright\begin{minipage}{\wd\tempbox}
\usebox{\tempbox}
\captionof{figure}{cantor set}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{mwe}` is entirely superfluous ;). Although the code answers the question, the explanation really doesnt :-). Unless I've completely misunderstood the explanation, the question or both.

Comment: What I mean is that you then find people with `\usepackage{mwe}` in their real documents. Usually as well as `graphicx` of course. `\usepackage{graphicx}` is much more transparent.

Comment: @cfr - Some people load every package they have in every document, but I see your point.  Should I also lose showframe?

Comment: For the record, if you are writing "It's easier to show than explain." then you are giving a lousy answer.

Comment: @Mstdmsyh - In terms of time and effort, it WAS easier to show than explain.  But thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I'd at least add a comment saying what `showframe` does and that it should be commented out in the document.